# How to run an Android Application in background?

Tags: android

I have created an Android app and it's working fine. The issue is that, when I press the back button of the phone, the application is closed, but I want to run the application in background also.

If possible, can anyone provide a pseudo code for the same, or give an idea of what can be used to implement this.?

Answer (score 1):

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
         if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
         {
            this.moveTaskToBack(true);
            return true;
         }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{ 
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) 
    { 
        this.moveTaskToBack(true); 
        return true;
    } 
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Service to run you app in background

You can use following tutorials for better understandings

[Service Tutorial 1](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html)

[Service Tutorial 2](https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/60/servicesdemo_using_android_services)

Answer (score 0):

You should go with Service if you want your Application's part to run in Background...
for E.g: Playing Music at the Same Time Browsing on the Internet

[Check this Out](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

[Tutorial Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html)

Hope This could help